How can you tell whether it's either voltage-current or voltage- voltage feedback?
The following circuits have different feedback.
Resistor \$R_F\$ senses the output voltage and returns a proportional current to node \$V_X\$. Thus, the feedback can be considered as the voltage-current type.

The circuit consists of two common-source stages, with RF and RS sensing the output voltage and returning a fraction thereof to the source of \$M_1\$.

The feedback network includes \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, and the transistor \$M_1\$.

What type is this ? is this voltage to voltage feedback?

How about the 5th one with BJT?

How can you tell what kind of feedback it is?

@ kile - because we can find some different definitions in the literature, you should clearly explain what you mean: To me, voltage-current feedback is a voltage caused feedback signal in form of a current (in short: Voltage caused current feedback).

@LvW I have updated definitions according to the book.

Take look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/474102/having-hard-time-to-identify-feedback-types/474105#474105

@G36 The pictures in the link can  not be displayed. Is there a way for you to show those?

@kile there is no issues on display pictures on my side.


First diagram: Voltage-controlled current feedback (two currents - driven from Vin resp. Vout - meet in a common node at the gate).
Second diagram: Voltage-controlled voltage feedback (the feedback voltage at the source of M1 is a portion of the output voltage).
Third diagram (with correction in response to Designanalogs comment): Voltage-controlled current feedback (two currents - input current Iin and the output current from M1 - meet in a common node at source of M2).


Disagree for the last one. M1 is part of the feedback network and, as such, it suppresses the changes in current. Voltage (out) - current (in) feedback.

@ Designanalog - you are right. I did overlook that M1 is NOT part of the main amplifier. I will correct my answer. Thank you.

@LvW How about the 4th one?

@Designalog How about the 4th one? Is this voltage to voltage?

@kile that's a bit more complicated. You have 2 feedback networks, IMHO. Shunt-series feedback that amplifies the gate voltage of M1 towards the output via the non-inverting formula (RE||Rs, mind you). And the other would be the inverting transfer from Vin to Vout. And inverting amplifier, IMHO, has a shunt-shunt feedback, and adds a series resistance (Rs) to convert Vin to a current. In the inv. transfer, RE is negligible (ideally).

@Designalog Could you please provide diagrams to illustrate? What is IMHO?

IMHO = in my humble opinion. Will add an answer in a few hours.

@ kile - I think, the 4th diagram shows again a voltage-controlled current feedback. This circuit is just an extended version of the 1st diagram. In general, as one property of current feedback, the signal input resistance is decreased (voltage feedback increases the signal input resistance). And the addition of Re does not change this scenario in principle. The addition of Re will not increase (or counteract the decrease of) the signal input resistance.

@Designalog Do you agree with LvW on 4th  diagram?

@kile I agree. The non-inverting transfer is shunt-series feedback only applicable to the VGS of M1 (which also applies for the 1st configuration, btw). But if you want to ignore that and only consider the feedback applied to Vin, then I fully agree with LvW.

@kile in short, RE only changes the non-inverting transfer that Vgs has towards the output; it doesn't do anything to the input (ideally).

@Designalog Shunt - series is current-current feedback.  How do you derive that? Could you please provide diagrams to illustrate? shunt-shunt is current-voltage feedback,

@kile I'm using the output - input convention. It's voltage-voltage feedback

@ Designanalog - voltage controlled voltage feedback for the 4th diagram? No - I cannot agree to this. How can you justify that? When the feedback signal is a voltage you always need a second input - in addition to the signal input (as in the 2nd diagram).

@LvW How about the 5th one with bipolar junction transistor. What type is this?

@Designalog How about the 5th one with bipolar junction transistor. What type is this?

@LvW I'm talking about the feedback type for the gate to source voltage, not the Vin input signal.

@kile 5th looks like current -to-current feedback to me at a first sight. Some local series-series feedback for the 1st stage.

@Designalog Is series-series feedback the same as  current-voltage feedback?

@kile No, the local feedback comment doesn't have anything to do with the overall feedback loop, which is series (out) - shunt (in).

@ Design analog - with respect to "gate to source" feedback (your comment): I suppose you are referring to DC stabilization (DC feedback) of the DC operating point, correct?
However, I think that this question has nothing to do with kile`s problem.

@ kile - the 5th circuit shows an overall feedback scheme which is a current-controlled current type. Each of the local feedback loops is a current-controlled voltage fedback. By the way - I must admit that I dislike expressions like "series-shunt" or "current-voltage" or similar expressions. I like clear desriptions (which cannot be misinterpretd) like for example: "current-controlled voltage" feedback.
